# FATAL EXCEPTION: main Android Studio App se cierra

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

les explico mi problema.

Tengo una App llamada Hexthour para visualización de vídeo, anteriormente había explicado que no podia compilarse la aplicación.

Por fin pude compilarla pero el problema sigue presentandose, porque ahora aunque se instala la aplicación la misma no se abre, cuando intenta abrirse se pone la pantalla negra 1 segundo o menos y se cierra de forma casi inmediata, sin mostrar ningún gráfico o error, esto lo hace tanto en el emulador de Android Studio como en un teléfono real.

No muestra ningún mensaje de error, pero esto es lo que sale del logcat.

No se si me puedan hechar una mano para saber que podría ser.

gracias de antemano.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): Process: net.nextrim.go, PID: 21055
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): 
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): ******************************************************************************
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): ******************************************************************************
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): 
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): 
E/AndroidRuntime(21055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7244)
E/AndroidRuntime(21055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780)
E/AndroidRuntime(21055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697)
E/AndroidRuntime(21055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(21055):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
E/AndroidRuntime(21055):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(21055):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(21055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime(21055):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21055):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime(21055):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): 
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): ******************************************************************************
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): ******************************************************************************
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): 
E/AndroidRuntime(21055): 
E/AndroidRuntime(21055):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhk.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.4.0:20)
E/AndroidRuntime(21055):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@20.4.0:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(21055):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7239)
E/AndroidRuntime(21055):    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error indica que tus anuncios estan incorrectamente inicializados, revisa :

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk

y tambièn:

https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest

Asegura usar la dependencia:

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.0.0'
```

y agregar el App Id en tu manifest (en `android:value` ):

```
...
...
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
</application>
```

Debes agregar el App Id en el meta dato de tu AndroidManifest.xml ya que de lo contrario, esta es la razòn por la cual se obtiene el error:

> The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly.